# What is the current DAG size? When do we expect to hit GPU limits?

Tags: mining, gpu, dag

I have two mining rigs running, one with 2GB GPUs and one with 8GB cards. Recently, the rig with the 2GB cards failed due to the inability to upload the DAG to the GPU.

What's the current DAG size for miners and when do we expect to hit GPU-relevant limits, e.g. 2GB, 3GB, 4GB and so on. Are there any precalculations available/possible?

Comment: Before being turned down from mining ground, low memory machines will be decreased the hashrate while the DAG file sizes increases to the milestones 3G 4G 8G

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The DAG started at 1 GB at the time of the Frontier launch, and increases by [approximately 0.73x per year](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash-Design-Rationale).  **That puts the current size at roughly 1.35 GB as of mid-January 2016** (feel free to comment with an exact link if anyone has one).

Following the same crude approximation:

- The 2GB limit will be hit around mid-December 2016
- The 3GB limit will be hit around mid-April 2018
- The 4GB limit will be hit around mid-September 2019

However, it's likely that [the switch to PoS](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9/why-does-ethereum-plan-to-move-to-proof-of-stake) will occur long before then.

For what it's worth, **certain GPUs require the DAG to be uploaded in chunks**.  You should search on the forums with the name of your card to find if this solution has worked for other users running the same hardware.

Comment: Is this correct what Jeff postet?
Cause i mean there a lot of Miners now...

Comment: @Scholli Yes, it is correct. The switch to PoS may not occur "long before" 2019, but still looks to be on track.

Comment: Following links in this thread I found this page where you can see approximately when a DAG size will end (https://investoon.com/tools/dag_size). You also have a calculator where you include the block_number and it tells you the size of the DAG (https://etherscan.io/blocks).

Answer (score 12):

As of June of 2017, the DAG size had grown past 2 GB. This other Q & A thread ([Where do I see the current dag size](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13001/where-do-i-see-the-current-dag-size?rq=1)) will tell you how to find the exact up-to-date number.

Answer (score 3):

If you need DAG size tracker you can visit [investoon.com/tools/dag_size](https://investoon.com/tools/dag_size) there you can see current DAG size and important epochs.